# Is it possible to apply entity fixed effects to a firth logit test?

Tags: logistic-regression

All,

Currently working with a large dataset (~1.6 million observations) with a relatively low number of rare events (~600ish). To summarize, I'm looking at the impact of 7 foreign-policy related independent variables to see the effect on whether a country, in any given year (1816 - 2000), initiates a militarized action against another country (i.e., the outcome variable is binary: either the country attacked or didn't).

Since the binary outcome variable is only 1 in ~600 cases, I'm using a firth logit test, but I think I need to account for country fixed effects. So my question is: does anyone know if it is possible to add entity fixed effects to a firth logit test?

If yes, wonderful! I'd like to add country fixed effects to my model in Stata (version 17). Thanks in advance for any and all insight!